# node express sessions - does secret need to be unique somehow?

Tags: node.js, express, session, session-cookies

So I'm using express-session https://github.com/expressjs/session and I was wondering if the secret needed to be unique for every user. I can't seem to find anything that says it does as the usage just lists:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}))
```

I'm currently just creating the secret using `bcrypt` but I'm not sure if this will impact sessions when I update my server file.

```
var salt1 = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
var salt2 = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
var secret = bcrypt.hashSync(salt1 + salt2, 10);
app.use(session({
    secret, // set this to a long random string!,
}));
```

Should the session be generated inside a function in itself, i.e. `function generateSession()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The secret is the same for all users.  The "secret" you supply simply acts as the salt for the session's hash function.  The method you're using is as good as any as it will generate a new salt each time the application is restarted.

Comment: So the salt wouldn't be the same as the secret every time the application is restarted? Does the salt algo change every time the application is restarted?

Comment: Correct.  It would be different every time the app started.  His implementation calls genSalt which is generating new random salts each time.  The bcrypt hash will be different every time.